# Split a long math equation

Tags: formatting

I get this error:

> `\begin{multline} allowed only in paragraph mode.`

```
\documentclass[multi={mymath},border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
     \begin{document}
        \begin{mymath}
        \begin{multline}
        \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+t\cos \theta, y_0 + t \sin \theta) - f(x_0,y_0)}{t} = \\  
    \frac{1}{t} \{ f_x(x_0,y_0) t\cos \theta + f_y (x_0,y_0) t \sin \theta + o(t)\} = f_x(x_0,y_0) \cos \theta + f_y(x_0,y_0) \sin \theta + o(1)
        \end{multline}
        \end{mymath}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `mymath` environment, if you don't mind?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have posted a code that contains an environment named `mymath`. Possibly/Probably, you have created that environment with a command `\newenvironment{mymath}{...}{...}`, but we don't have this definition. So, it is impossible for someone to guess this definition and help you. You should add anything needed for your code to be able to compile (from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}`).

Comment: I define a new environment mymath, which is basically inline math with display style.

Comment: If it were compilable I wouldn't even ask

Comment: That is not the error I get. `multline` needs `amsmath`

Comment: @JouleV standalone can apparently define this for you. But it does not work in this case. It does however if you wrap the multline in a minipage.

Comment: @JouleV the OP apparently want to make an image, so standalone seems reasonable here. It just does not work the way they wanted it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- `multline` has not to be inside any math environment
- if you for some reason like to have inside, then an equivalent environment is `multlined` provided by package `mathtools`
- your math environment is not known, so its sense can't be evaluated
- I would retype your equation as is shown above. code for it is:

  ```
  \documentclass[preview, border=1pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{mathtools}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
          \MoveEqLeft
   \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+t\cos \theta, y_0 + t \sin \theta) - f(x_0,y_0)}{t}         \\
      & = \frac{1}{t} \{ f_x(x_0,y_0) t\cos \theta + f_y (x_0,y_0) t \sin \theta + o(t)\} \\
      & = f_x(x_0,y_0) \cos \theta + f_y(x_0,y_0) \sin \theta + o(1)
      \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
      \end{document}
  ```

Comment: That is not what the standalone manual says about the `multi` key. It does exist.

Answer (score 3):

You get a similar error also with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A &= B \\
  &= C
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

You have to activate the `varwidth` option, in order to have equation numbers. Besides, of course, loading `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[multi={mymath},border=1pt,varwidth=14cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{mymath}
\begin{multline}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+t\cos \theta, y_0 + t \sin \theta) - f(x_0,y_0)}{t} = \\
\frac{1}{t} \{ f_x(x_0,y_0) t\cos \theta + f_y (x_0,y_0) t \sin \theta + o(t)\} =
  f_x(x_0,y_0) \cos \theta + f_y(x_0,y_0) \sin \theta + o(1)
\end{multline}
\end{mymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]